# How to disable ldap and allow local authentication in debian server?

Tags: debian, ldap, openldap

I have debian server  Debian 3.2.81-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux.
I want to disable openldap and enable local authentication.
I see `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf` file  which has ldap entry.

I have ran service slapd stop; if server is rebooted, will the slapd service start automatically?

Answer (score 2):

I would utilize `authconfig` because you aren't really indicating which method of LDAP authentication you're using.  Try this command:

`authconfig --disableldapauth --disableldap --enableshadow --updateall`

You will need to add users to the local passwd file using the `useradd` command

`useradd foouser`

Comment: above command is for redhat or centos server.This is a debian server.it os openldap

Comment: so sorry, for Debian there's a bunch of files you need to modify.  But I think the meat and potatoes is in `/etc/pam.d/`  barring that, if you dont want to use LDAP ever again, you can uninstall it completely using:

`apt-get remove --purge slapd`

Comment: I would suggest adding the Debian/Ubuntu commands AND adding the reenable commands for all versions for completeness.